# Create a UIImage with UIGestureRecognizer at runtime

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to be able to add a new UIImageView of a certain size which should have a few UIGestureRecognizers detecting touch on the UIImageView.

How does one subclass UIImageView or how would this be best achieved?

I want the user to be able to add UIImageViews as they want at runtime and then the gestureRecognizer will allow them to manipulate the views.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you just forgot to enable userInteractions.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]] autorelease];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)] autorelease];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: can I get the actual tapping pixel position on UIImage ?